# Entity Framework update on large table failing - Exception: The wait operation timed out

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, entity-framework-6

Entity Framework 6.1.3 update on a large table is failing in the production environment

Exception:

> The wait operation timed out

I have an `Issue` table with nearly 8000000 records. While inserting records, the exception occurs

> The wait operation timed out

While inserting record we do some background tasks in on SQL transaction.

1. Insert values in the `Notification` table (to send a notification to the user).
2. Insert values in the `Change` table. The `Change` table keeps the history changed value, old value, new value, etc. And I think this transaction causes the timeout exception. Need some inputs

```
-- statement #1
begin transaction with isolation level: ReadCommitted

-- statement #2
UPDATE [dbo].[Issues]
SET [CategoryID] = @0, [SubcategoryID] = @1, [HandlerID] = @2, [Modified] = @3, [RegionID] = @4, [TeamID] = @5, [Closed] = @6, [Address] = @7, [AddressDetails] = @8, [Description] = @9, [Location] = @10, [Status] = @11, [Visibility] = @12, [ReportedBy_Address] = @13, [ReportedBy_EmailAddress] = @14, [ReportedBy_Name] = @15, [ReportedBy_PhoneNumber] = @16, [ForwardedMessage] = @17, [IsUrgent] = @18, [IsNewlyAssigned] = @19, [CategoryField] = @20, [IntegrationFault] = @21
WHERE ([ID] = @22)

-- statement #3
INSERT [dbo].[ChangeSets]([Created], [ApplicationID], [UserID])
VALUES (@0, @1, NULL)
SELECT [ID]
FROM [dbo].[ChangeSets]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [ID] = scope_identity()

-- statement #4
DECLARE @generated_keys table([ID] uniqueidentifier)
INSERT [dbo].[Changes]([ChangeSetID], [EntityID], [Name], [Type], [PreviousValue], [NewValue])
OUTPUT inserted.[ID] INTO @generated_keys
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5)
SELECT t.[ID]
FROM @generated_keys AS g JOIN [dbo].[Changes] AS t ON g.[ID] = t.[ID]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0

-- statement #5
DECLARE @generated_keys table([ID] uniqueidentifier)
INSERT [dbo].[Changes]([ChangeSetID], [EntityID], [Name], [Type], [PreviousValue], [NewValue])
OUTPUT inserted.[ID] INTO @generated_keys
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5)
SELECT t.[ID]
FROM @generated_keys AS g JOIN [dbo].[Changes] AS t ON g.[ID] = t.[ID]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0

-- statement #6
DECLARE @generated_keys table([ID] uniqueidentifier)
INSERT [dbo].[Changes]([ChangeSetID], [EntityID], [Name], [Type], [PreviousValue], [NewValue])
OUTPUT inserted.[ID] INTO @generated_keys
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5)
SELECT t.[ID]
FROM @generated_keys AS g JOIN [dbo].[Changes] AS t ON g.[ID] = t.[ID]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0

-- statement #7
DECLARE @generated_keys table([ID] uniqueidentifier)
INSERT [dbo].[Changes]([ChangeSetID], [EntityID], [Name], [Type], [PreviousValue], [NewValue])
OUTPUT inserted.[ID] INTO @generated_keys
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5)
SELECT t.[ID]
FROM @generated_keys AS g JOIN [dbo].[Changes] AS t ON g.[ID] = t.[ID]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0

-- statement #8
DECLARE @generated_keys table([ID] uniqueidentifier)
INSERT [dbo].[Changes]([ChangeSetID], [EntityID], [Name], [Type], [PreviousValue], [NewValue])
OUTPUT inserted.[ID] INTO @generated_keys
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5)
SELECT t.[ID]
FROM @generated_keys AS g JOIN [dbo].[Changes] AS t ON g.[ID] = t.[ID]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0

-- statement #9
DECLARE @generated_keys table([ID] uniqueidentifier)
INSERT [dbo].[Changes]([ChangeSetID], [EntityID], [Name], [Type], [PreviousValue], [NewValue])
OUTPUT inserted.[ID] INTO @generated_keys
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5)
SELECT t.[ID]
FROM @generated_keys AS g JOIN [dbo].[Changes] AS t ON g.[ID] = t.[ID]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0

-- statement #10
DECLARE @generated_keys table([ID] uniqueidentifier)
INSERT [dbo].[Changes]([ChangeSetID], [EntityID], [Name], [Type], [PreviousValue], [NewValue])
OUTPUT inserted.[ID] INTO @generated_keys
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5)
SELECT t.[ID]
FROM @generated_keys AS g JOIN [dbo].[Changes] AS t ON g.[ID] = t.[ID]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0

-- statement #11
DECLARE @generated_keys table([ID] uniqueidentifier)
INSERT [dbo].[Changes]([ChangeSetID], [EntityID], [Name], [Type], [PreviousValue], [NewValue])
OUTPUT inserted.[ID] INTO @generated_keys
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5)
SELECT t.[ID]
FROM @generated_keys AS g JOIN [dbo].[Changes] AS t ON g.[ID] = t.[ID]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0

-- statement #12
DECLARE @generated_keys table([ID] uniqueidentifier)
INSERT [dbo].[Changes]([ChangeSetID], [EntityID], [Name], [Type], [PreviousValue], [NewValue])
OUTPUT inserted.[ID] INTO @generated_keys
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5)
SELECT t.[ID]
FROM @generated_keys AS g JOIN [dbo].[Changes] AS t ON g.[ID] = t.[ID]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0

-- statement #13
DECLARE @generated_keys table([ID] uniqueidentifier)
INSERT [dbo].[Changes]([ChangeSetID], [EntityID], [Name], [Type], [PreviousValue], [NewValue])
OUTPUT inserted.[ID] INTO @generated_keys
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5)
SELECT t.[ID]
FROM @generated_keys AS g JOIN [dbo].[Changes] AS t ON g.[ID] = t.[ID]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0

-- statement #14
DECLARE @generated_keys table([ID] uniqueidentifier)
INSERT [dbo].[Changes]([ChangeSetID], [EntityID], [Name], [Type], [PreviousValue], [NewValue])
OUTPUT inserted.[ID] INTO @generated_keys
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5)
SELECT t.[ID]
FROM @generated_keys AS g JOIN [dbo].[Changes] AS t ON g.[ID] = t.[ID]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0

-- statement #15
DECLARE @generated_keys table([ID] uniqueidentifier)
INSERT [dbo].[Changes]([ChangeSetID], [EntityID], [Name], [Type], [PreviousValue], [NewValue])
OUTPUT inserted.[ID] INTO @generated_keys
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5)
SELECT t.[ID]
FROM @generated_keys AS g JOIN [dbo].[Changes] AS t ON g.[ID] = t.[ID]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0

-- statement #16
DECLARE @generated_keys table([ID] uniqueidentifier)
INSERT [dbo].[Changes]([ChangeSetID], [EntityID], [Name], [Type], [PreviousValue], [NewValue])
OUTPUT inserted.[ID] INTO @generated_keys
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5)
SELECT t.[ID]
FROM @generated_keys AS g JOIN [dbo].[Changes] AS t ON g.[ID] = t.[ID]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0

-- statement #17
DECLARE @generated_keys table([ID] uniqueidentifier)
INSERT [dbo].[Changes]([ChangeSetID], [EntityID], [Name], [Type], [PreviousValue], [NewValue])
OUTPUT inserted.[ID] INTO @generated_keys
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5)
SELECT t.[ID]
FROM @generated_keys AS g JOIN [dbo].[Changes] AS t ON g.[ID] = t.[ID]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0

-- statement #18
DECLARE @generated_keys table([ID] uniqueidentifier)
INSERT [dbo].[Changes]([ChangeSetID], [EntityID], [Name], [Type], [PreviousValue], [NewValue])
OUTPUT inserted.[ID] INTO @generated_keys
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5)
SELECT t.[ID]
FROM @generated_keys AS g JOIN [dbo].[Changes] AS t ON g.[ID] = t.[ID]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0

-- statement #19
DECLARE @generated_keys table([ID] uniqueidentifier)
INSERT [dbo].[Changes]([ChangeSetID], [EntityID], [Name], [Type], [PreviousValue], [NewValue])
OUTPUT inserted.[ID] INTO @generated_keys
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5)
SELECT t.[ID]
FROM @generated_keys AS g JOIN [dbo].[Changes] AS t ON g.[ID] = t.[ID]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0

-- statement #20
DECLARE @generated_keys table([ID] uniqueidentifier)
INSERT [dbo].[Changes]([ChangeSetID], [EntityID], [Name], [Type], [PreviousValue], [NewValue])
OUTPUT inserted.[ID] INTO @generated_keys
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5)
SELECT t.[ID]
FROM @generated_keys AS g JOIN [dbo].[Changes] AS t ON g.[ID] = t.[ID]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0

-- statement #21
DECLARE @generated_keys table([ID] uniqueidentifier)
INSERT [dbo].[Changes]([ChangeSetID], [EntityID], [Name], [Type], [PreviousValue], [NewValue])
OUTPUT inserted.[ID] INTO @generated_keys
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5)
SELECT t.[ID]
FROM @generated_keys AS g JOIN [dbo].[Changes] AS t ON g.[ID] = t.[ID]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0

-- statement #22
DECLARE @generated_keys table([ID] uniqueidentifier)
INSERT [dbo].[Notifications]([Created], [CreatedByID], [Modified], [ModifiedByID], [UserID], [Person_Address], [Person_EmailAddress], [Person_Name], [Person_PhoneNumber], [Type], [IssueID], [CommentID], [AttachmentID], [RegionID], [OrganizationID], [IsHidden], [IsRead])
OUTPUT inserted.[ID] INTO @generated_keys
VALUES (@0, NULL, NULL, NULL, @1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, @2, @3, NULL, NULL, @4, @5, @6, @7)
SELECT t.[ID]
FROM @generated_keys AS g JOIN [dbo].[Notifications] AS t ON g.[ID] = t.[ID]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0

-- statement #23
DECLARE @generated_keys table([ID] uniqueidentifier)
INSERT [dbo].[Notifications]([Created], [CreatedByID], [Modified], [ModifiedByID], [UserID], [Person_Address], [Person_EmailAddress], [Person_Name], [Person_PhoneNumber], [Type], [IssueID], [CommentID], [AttachmentID], [RegionID], [OrganizationID], [IsHidden], [IsRead])
OUTPUT inserted.[ID] INTO @generated_keys
VALUES (@0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, @1, @2, NULL, @3, @4, NULL, NULL, @5, @6, @7, @8)
SELECT t.[ID]
FROM @generated_keys AS g JOIN [dbo].[Notifications] AS t ON g.[ID] = t.[ID]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0

-- statement #24
DECLARE @generated_keys table([ID] uniqueidentifier)
INSERT [dbo].[Notifications]([Created], [CreatedByID], [Modified], [ModifiedByID], [UserID], [Person_Address], [Person_EmailAddress], [Person_Name], [Person_PhoneNumber], [Type], [IssueID], [CommentID], [AttachmentID], [RegionID], [OrganizationID], [IsHidden], [IsRead])
OUTPUT inserted.[ID] INTO @generated_keys
VALUES (@0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, NULL, NULL, @7, @8, @9, @10)
SELECT t.[ID]
FROM @generated_keys AS g JOIN [dbo].[Notifications] AS t ON g.[ID] = t.[ID]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0

-- statement #25
commit transaction
```

Exception

> Error: System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error
> occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for
> details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error
> occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for
> details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Execution Timeout
> Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the
> operation or the server is not responding. --->
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out ---
> End of inner exception stack trace --- at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
> Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalEndExecuteNonQuery(IAsyncResult asyncResult, String endMethod, Boolean isInternal) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryInternal(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryAsync(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
> iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.d__0.MoveNext() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.d__3d`1.MoveNext() ---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.d__39.MoveNext() --- End
> of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at
> System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.d__9`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.d__31.MoveNext() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Decos.Fixi.Data.FixiContext.d__80.MoveNext() in E:\_work4\10\s\Fixi2\Main\Decos.Fixi.Api\Decos.Fixi.Data\FixiContext.cs:line 200 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at Decos.Fixi.Data.FixiContext.d__80.MoveNext() in E:\_work4\10\s\Fixi2\Main\Decos.Fixi.Api\Decos.Fixi.Data\FixiContext.cs:line 207 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Decos.Fixi.Data.Services.ServiceBase`2.d__15.MoveNext() in
> E:_work4\10\s\Fixi2\Main\Decos.Fixi.Api\Decos.Fixi.Data\Services\ServiceBase.cs:line
> 181 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was
> thrown --- at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at Decos.Fixi.Data.Services.IssueService.d__19.MoveNext() in
> E:_work4\10\s\Fixi2\Main\Decos.Fixi.Api\Decos.Fixi.Data\Services\IssueService.cs:line
> 277 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was
> thrown --- at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at
> Decos.Fixi.WebApi.Controllers.IssuesController.d__20.MoveNext() in
> E:_work4\10\s\Fixi2\Main\Decos.Fixi.Api\Decos.Fixi.WebApi\Controllers\IssuesController.cs:line
> 593 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was
> thrown --- at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at
> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__3`1.MoveNext() --- End
> of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext() --- End
> of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext() --- End
> of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext() --- End
> of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext() --- End
> of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at
> System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at
> Decos.Fixi.WebApi.Annotations.AuthenticateApplicationAttribute.d__8.MoveNext()
> in
> E:_work4\10\s\Fixi2\Main\Decos.Fixi.Api\Decos.Fixi.WebApi\Annotations\ApplicationAuthenticationAttribute.cs:line
> 108 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was
> thrown --- at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) at
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what version of EF you're using, but regardless you need to set the command timeout. It defaults to 30 seconds so that won't work for you.

In EF 6, it was set like this: 
this.context.Database.CommandTimeout = 0;
EF 5, something like this: ((IObjectContextAdapter)this.context).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 0;
In EF core:
this.context.Database.SetCommandTimeout(0);

The value is in seconds. If you set the value to 0, it's "unlimited". I'd say that's what you need.

Comment: I am using EF 6. And CommandTimeout is 90 sec. But still, the timeout occurs.